# Why the value of x and y is 1

Tags: c

```
union test{  
    unsigned int x: 3; 
    unsigned int y: 3; 
    int z;}; 
int main(){      
 union test t;   
 t.x = 5;  
 t.y = 4;   
 t.z = 1; 
 printf("t.x = %d, t.y = %d, t.z = %d", t.x, t.y, t.z);  
 return 0;
}
```

I can not understand why the value of x and y is 1,
any help is appreciated thanks .

EDIT:
thanks all of you for the inputs ,you  have asked for outputs  I don't have a compiler at present anyway way i compiled the code online and these are the outputs

```
for z= 1  :      t.x = 1, t.y = 1, t.z = 1

for z= 2  :      t.x = 2, t.y = 2, t.z = 2

for z= 10 :      t.x = 2, t.y = 2, t.z = 10

for z= 30 :      t.x = 6, t.y = 6, t.z = 30
```

why these strange outputs ??

Comment: I suggest you include the printout from your printf in the question. I assume it says 1 on the first positions at least.

Comment: Einar Sundgren i have the printfs can you explain me the behaviour ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compiler allocate memory for largest `union` member. Memory for `z` will be allocated in this case. Since last assignment make `z` to have value `1`, only this value will be there in memory overriding the previous values. So, the last 3 bits stored in allocated memory is `001`. Accessing other `3` bit members will give result `1`.

For `z` equals to `2`, `10`, and `30` , last `3` bits are `010`, `010` and `110` respectively which are equal to `2`, `2` and `6` respectively in decimal.

Answer (score 1):

It's a union, that's the way unions work. All of the member variables (x,y,z) are at the same address in memory, so if you change one, you change them all. Technically you should only read the last one that you wrote. Writing to `z` and then reading from `x` or `y` is unspecified behavior.

From the C-11 draft specification §6.2.6.1

> When a value is stored in a member of an object of union type, the
>   bytes of the object representation that do not correspond to that
>   member but do correspond to other members take unspecified values.

---

In response to the edit:
The lower three bits of 10 decimal are `010` binary which is 2 decimal.
The lower three bits of 30 decimal are `110` binary which is 6 decimal.

Comment: No. It will not invoke UB.

Comment: @haccks true, unspecified behavior, not undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

In Union, we can use one member at a time. So at last you assign the value as 1.Refer [here.](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_unions.htm)

Union will take the memory which having the highest size in that member. So from that memory all the members have to work in that. At last `z` will access the memory then make the value as one.

All the members will use the same memory so first two members got the value as one.

You can verify like this. Make a `printf` after assigning every value.

```
t.x=5;
printf("t.x = %d, t.y = %d, t.z = %d", t.x, t.y, t.z);
t.y=4
printf("t.x = %d, t.y = %d, t.z = %d", t.x, t.y, t.z);
t.z=1;
printf("t.x = %d, t.y = %d, t.z = %d", t.x, t.y, t.z);
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong in it.

Last 3 bits of z are shared with x and y.

**for z= 30 t.x = 6, t.y = 6, t.z = 30**

z= 0x1E = 00011110.

t.x = 110 = 6

t.y = 110 = 6